# How to pass additional parameters to `under` subroutine in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have two routes:

```
$auth =  $r->under( \&auth );
$auth->get( "/test",   { level => 'user' }  )->to( "C#A1" );
$auth->get( "/secure", { level => 'admin' } )->to( "C#A2" );
```

I use `under` to check access level. But when `auth` subroutine is called it has not yet { level } value.
The { level } will be available only at action.

How better pass to &auth function required user level for target route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found answer. I should use [`stack`](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Routes/Match#stack) method:

```
sub auth {
    ...
    return 1   if $c->match->stack->[-1]{ level } <= $user->level;
}
```

It contains:

```
[
  { api => 1, cb => sub { ... } },                     # stash at &auth
  { api => 1, cb => sub { ... }, level => "user" },    # stash at &C#A*
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to have level be a separate sub that sets the level and use that for routes.

```
my $user  = $r->under('/user' )->to('auth#check_user' );
my $admin = $r->under('/admin')->to('auth#check_admin');
$user ->get("/test"  )->to("C#A1");
$admin->get("/secure")->to("C#A2");
```

This example would have your routes be `/user/test` and `/admin/secure`. Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: It would have `/user/admin/secure`. Check your code please

Comment: I have this case. But to my mind it is not good approach, because rights checking in two places looks insecure